# php based Business Instelligence for Process Maker BPM

Tags: business-intelligence

i use process maker as my BPM System and i want to use php based BI (Business Intelligence) system for make report from Process Maker results .
can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

[ProcessMaker](http://www.processmaker.com/) recommends [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/download/) as its BI solution to be integrated with.

Check this: [ProcessMaker to offer Advanced Business Intelligence in its BPM software](http://www.processmaker.com/press-releases/processmaker-offer-advanced-business-intelligence-its-bpm-software)

However, be aware that Pentaho is Java-based. I've not found any PHP-based BI suite yet.

That said, I've been using ProcessMaker for 2 years and think ad-hoc reporting is a feature it still lacks. This is mainly due to the fact that [it stores cases data in a serialized form](http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/Triggers#Variable_Storage), so reporting is not straigthforward.

Check this post: [Unserialize case APP_DATA and show into a GRID in a DYNAFORM](http://forum.processmaker.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3637) to have an idea how it works.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, Processmaker has ended their support of their Pentaho Plugin.
I've been trying with PHP Report Maker and getting good success so far.
http://www.hkvstore.com/phpreportmaker/